# State being passed to all items in array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent form component and a child `<Input>` component. I'm mapping through an array of objects to return the various `<Input>` fields I want to render. However when passing the state through, it seems to be passing the same state through to *all* the returned input fields instead of each individual one.

I want each input's value to be set in state. So for example I want the "Full name" input to have its own value, same for email, etc. At the moment when I type a value into 1 field, the value gets applied to *all* fields in the map.

What am I doing wrong here?

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { formFieldsData } from './FormFields';
import Input from './Input';

export default function Form() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <form>
            {formFieldsData.map((item) => (
                <Input
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    label={item.label}
                    type={item.type}
                    placeholder={item.placeholder}
                    inputValue={inputValue}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
            ))}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './forms.module.scss';
import RangeInput from './RangeInput';

export default function Input({ inputValue, onChange, type, id, placeholder = '', label }) {

    return (
        <div className={styles.form__row}>
            <label htmlFor={id}>{label}: {inputValue}</label>
                <input
                    required
                    type={type}
                    id={id}
                    name={id}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    className={styles.input}
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
        </div>
    )
}
```

formsFieldData.js

```
export const formFieldsData = [
  {
    label: 'Full name',
    type: 'text',
    id: 'fullName',
    placeholder: 'Your full name'
  },
  {
    label: 'Email',
    type: 'email',
    id: 'emailAddress',
    placeholder: 'Please enter your email address'
  },
  {
    label: 'Date of birth',
    type: 'date',
    id: 'dateOfBirth',
  },
  {
    label: 'Favourite colour',
    type: 'color',
    id: 'favouriteColour',
  },
  {
    label: 'Salary',
    type: 'range',
    id: 'salary',
  },  
];
```

Comment: show us `formFieldsData `

Comment: Maybe have more than one value? Why _wouldn't_ it be shared?

Comment: any console errors? I would `console.log` each `item` in here: `{formFieldsData.map((item) => (...`

Comment: No console errors. The reason I'm asking is because I want each input's value to be set in state. So for example I want the "Full name" input to have it's own value, same for email etc. At the moment when I type a value into 1 field, the value gets applied to ALL fields in the map.

Comment: "*it seems to be passing the same state through to all the returned input fields instead of each individual one.*" - well you **have** only a single string state in your form component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the same value to all the Input. To fix this, you have to manage an array in your state :

`const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([]);`

You can identify every input with the index of your array by passing it as a prop as you already do, and with this id, properly edit the state :

```
const handleChange = (e, index) => {
  const newInputValues = [...inputValues];
  newInputValues[index] = e.target.value;
  setInputValues(newInputValues);
}
```

Note that if each input have a unique label, you can identify them with it, which would be easier to read in debug, something like :

`setInputValues([...inputValues, [label] = e.target.value])`